# Competing ItemsSource binding and SelectedItem binding

Tags: mvvm, uwp

I have a UWP app based on Template10 Minimal that is used to collect customer data; some of the views have combobox/listbox controls whose ItemsSource is dependent on the selected item of another combobox/listbox control. Ex. State and City where the City list would be populated based on the selected State.

This works fine on first load but when a user returns to the view and I try to restore their initial selections then it sometimes fails to set the selected city. I think this is because the SelectionChanged of the state (which clears and repopulates the list of cities) fires after the SlectedCity property of the viewmodel is set.

Whats the right way to handle this? It feels like it's a timing issue and depending on if the itemsource of the list is set first or if the selecteditem property is set first.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements. Basically what I think you're missing out on is the navigation cache. In your page where you want to keep the data when navigating out, in its constructor set the navigation cache mode to enabled. To do so, in your page code behind constructor (supposing your page name is `MainPage.xaml` so in your constructor

```
Public MainPage ()
{
    NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
 }
```

Please note, since you're using Template 10, in your `app.xaml.cs`
In the constructor you have your `CacheMaxDuration` set to `settings.cacheMaxDuration`.

I am sorry for the formatting, I am using a mobile device. Let me know if I can help further